# How do I get an M-Audio KeyStudio 25 to work?

Tags: hardware, compatibility

Has anyone been able to use any M-Audio midi devices successfully? (the box says Mac only). I am using an M-Audio KeyStudio 25.

Comment: Do you see your device listed in `aconnect -i` output, after you plug it in and turn it on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can usually check compatibility with devices on the alsa-project's main site:

http://alsa-project.org/

I couldn't find the keystudio on there. If this keyboard does not work then you could use the MIDI out port (it seems it has one) with a compatible MIDI out->USB device (The M-Audio Uno is one supported device, ~20 dollars).

Of course, with any sort of audio product on unsupported Operating Systems the best course of action is to see if you can test it out beforehand to make sure it does indeed work or not.

You can see what's plugged in your USB devices by issuing the command "lsusb" in a terminal. If the keystudio (or something similar) is listed then you may have a pretty good chance of compatibility.